# What is the basic architecture of Magento API?

Tags: magento-1.7, api

Even though there are number of articles about magento API, no one clearly provides information about how it works in magento system. Most of them have provided source codes to explain pieces of magento API. Cannot grab a clear idea about what is the basic flow of magento API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the flow.

1). Made an `http` request to a `URL`.

2). Send request to the controller action in `Mage_Api` by magento's standard routing system.

3). This controller action creates a `Magento API Server Object`.

4). Initialize the object with `API type`. (eg: SOAP , Xml-RPC, etc)

5). Call the `run()` method which is located inside this server object.